Strange non-normal distribution histogram when applying Hadamard gate in a loop
Recently I have explored Q# quantum programming language. My basic test was this,- for 10000 times in a loop reset qubit to |0>, then apply Hadamard gate, measure qubit state and aggregate (|0>,|1>) average probability tuple. Then I repeat this experiment for 10 000 "shots" for drawing experiment histogram in VScode.
For the reference, my full Q# test code :
namespace Experiment {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;

    @EntryPoint()
    operation test(): (Double, Double) {
        use q = Qubit();

        mutable wasZero = 0.0;
        let trials = 10000;
        for index in 1 .. trials {
            // Init to |0> state
            Reset(q);
            // Apply Hadamard gate
            H(q);
            // Aggregate statistics
            let r = M(q);
            if (r==Zero) {
                set wasZero +=1.0;
            }
        }

        // "Free" alocated qubit before exiting from program
        Reset(q);
        // From statistics calculate average state vector after transformation
        let avgState = (    wasZero/IntAsDouble(trials), 
                        1.0-wasZero/IntAsDouble(trials)
                       ); 
        return avgState;
    }

}

What I get is this :

I would expect to get a normal distribution with maximum at (1/2,1/2), but instead what I saw is darker stripes, (inside supposed to be a Gaussian curve),- marked with yellow arrows in histogram.
Question,- What is the cause of these periodic Gaussian "abnormalities" ? Is this some random number generator issues (I run this locally in VScode studio in quantum simulator), or simply graphics/rendering issue not related to quantum simulator ?
Thanks.

It is hard to tell exactly what are the arrows pointing at. I assume you are not refering to the vertical statistical disturbance that adds some noise to the expected Gaussian curve (increasing the number of shots will get you closer to a smooth curve).
My guess is that it is a rendering problem. Maybe your histogram bars have a slightly darker outline and overlap each other causing something analogous to a Moiré pattern. Does changing the zoom level of the histogram change to periodicity of the darker stripes?
Your picture is just an histogram that aggregates numerical values from a list. You can try exporting this list and plot it as an histogram with a different plotting system than the one of VSCode to confirm it is indeed a rendering problem.

It's not that hard to see what arrows are pointing at,- I've updated the picture with region where I have explicitly applied color enhance algorithm in GIMP.

I strongly suspect the Moiré effect then. You can try to play with VSCode renderer's settings (x-axis scale) or with a different plotting tool.

Confirmed,- rendering issue. On histogram window resize- black stripe width / density changes, albeit histogram calculation is fully completed. So what is left is bar overlapping / spaces between issue on too small image scale. Thanks.
